# Group representations as module categories?

Tags: category-theory, representation-theory

I am studying module categories and in the book by Etingof et al. it is said that
the notion of module category categorifies the notion of module over a ring.
How do finite dimensional representations of a (say finite) group $G$,
i.e. $\mathbb{C}G$-modules, fit into this picture?

For me a module category over a monoidal category $\mathcal{C}$ is a category $\mathcal{M}$
equipped with a bifunctor
$\otimes : \mathcal{C}\times \mathcal{M}\rightarrow \mathcal{M},$
satisfying some constraints.

More concretely: Which categories should I choose for $\mathcal{C}$ and $\mathcal{M}$ to reproduce the representation theory of $G$ over $\mathbb{C}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A set $S$ can be viewed as a category $\underline{S}$ by imposing $\mathrm{ob}(\underline{S}) = S$ and formally adding (only) identities for morphisms. In this way a monoid $A$ can be viewed as a monoidal category $\underline{A}$.

In this setting, a module $M$ over $A$ is the same as a module category $\underline{M}$ over $\underline{A}$.

*Aside:*
(There is yet another way to categorify set-theoretical modules which is not the one you ask.)

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a category. Then a $\mathcal{C}$-*module* is a functor $\mathcal{C}\rightarrow \operatorname{Set}$ (or into $\mathrm{Vec}$ if you want linear structures). This is a categorification: Consider $\mathcal{C} = BA$ to be the category with one object and morphisms given by.$ A$.

Comment: Thanks! It's more basic than I had imagined.

Comment: Along the lines of your last statement: Would it also be sensible to consider functors from the delooping of the monoidal category $\mathcal{C}$ into Vec? I would like objects of the category to be mapped to endomorphisms.

Comment: @david if $B\mathcal{C}$ denotes the delooping (2-category with 1 object) of $ \mathcal{C}$ then a module category $\mathcal{M}$ should be roughly the same as a 2-functor $B\mathcal{C}\rightarrow \mathrm{2Vect}$.